# Using alias for referenced variables in capture list of lambda?

Tags: visual-c++, lambda, c++14, pass-by-reference

With a lambda, is it not possible to use an alias for a variable that is in the capture list (by reference)?

```
auto AddSlip = [rFile = &fileCSV](COleDateTime datMeeting)
{

}
```

That won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With a lambda, is it not possible to use an alias for a variable that is in the capture list (by reference)?

Yes: it's possible. Starting from C++14.

Not in your way

```
auto AddSlip = [rFile = &fileCSV](COleDateTime datMeeting)
```

because `rFile` become the copy of the pointer to `fileCSV`; the syntax you're looking for is the following

```
auto AddSlip = [&rFile = fileCSV](COleDateTime datMeeting)
```

or, if you want a **const** reference,

```
auto AddSlip = [&rFile = std::as_const(fileCSV)](COleDateTime datMeeting)
```

Comment: Thank you for the examples and explanations. I don't think I want to use a `const` reference because it is a text file which is being serialized to.